# Estimation of parameters for a random effect model

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, panel-data

I want to fit a simple one-way random effect model, i.e.
\begin{equation}
y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij},
\end{equation}

where

$\mu$ denotes the mean

$\alpha_i$ the effect of the $i$-th threatment,

$\epsilon_{ij}$ the within individual variation or random error with $j = 1, \ldots ,k_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, m$.

The model assumes
$$\alpha_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\alpha^2), \qquad  \epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2),$$
where $\alpha_i$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$ are independent $\forall i,j$.

I have longitudinal data and know that with the **lme4** package in R, I can get my estimators with Maximum likelihood and Restricted maximum likelihood methods. BUT I can't find any good literature on this theory for the case of an unbalanced design.

I know this is a simple case of a linear mixed model, where solutions of likelihood estimates are obtained numerically. Nevertheless, the literature either suggests solving this numerically or just using the ANOVA-estimators, which are not as good as the likelihood approaches. I only find good analytical solutions for the balanced case of a linear mixed model or the random effects model.

Do you have any suggestions or good literature such that I understand how one estimates $\sigma_\alpha$, $\sigma$, and $\mu$?

Comment: Is your error correctly formulated? This is a model for independent data.

Comment: Yes it is. (it is the standard defintion of a random effects model)
Only the m induviduals are independent. (i = 1,...,m)
The already longitudinal data from the ith induvidual: yi,1 ,..., yik_i is dependent! As all of them are modeled with the same realisation of alpha_i.
Observations from different induviduals are considered to be independent.

-> The goal is to get a approximation of the distribution and the correlation.
With it the correlation for measurements of the same induvidual is 
$$\frac{\sigma_\alpha^2}{\sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2}$$.

Comment: The $\alpha_i$ term needs clarity, because you say that it is the effect of the $i$-th *treatment*. One might guess treatment is polytomous and estimated with ANOVA contrast... and giving a distribution might just mean you are using a Bayesian approach. If you mean the $\alpha_i$ to be a random intercept, thus inducing an exchangeable correlation structure as you have written in the comment, I would say the $\alpha_i$ is the common mean difference for the $i$-th cluster from the grand mean ($\mu$), or just say it's a random intercept.

Comment: Also, is there no treatment or other fixed effect covariate besides the intercept in the model?

Comment: $\alpha_i$ is not the treatment.
It should be seen as variation within induvidual. 
EX: i represents countries and j represents the index of observation. 
Then $y_{ij}$ can represent the 
gross domestic product and $\alpha_i$ the variation over the years/over the measurements in the longitudinal study. 

Thus i get an estimator of the distribution as well as how variable the gross domestic product varies in a country over the years.

Thank You :)

(I dont mean that it is the random intercept as you see :D)

Comment: So is your question then just "how do I fit a random effects model"? If so, are you using R? The question is off topic for this site, but it really is no more complicated than `require(lme4)` and `lme(y ~ (1|id))`.

Comment: Yes i know, but what is the math behind it.
I know that there might be a numerical solution using the EM-Algorithm but ask myself if there can be a exlicit solution for the estimators like in the balanced case. 
Thanks